# MainActivity cannot be cast to Interface

Tags: java, android, interface

I'm trying to share variables between fragments, using interfaces. My problem is that I get this error : `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.application.activities.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.application.ListGeneratedInterface`

Here is a part of my fragment :

```
public class MealsFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    EditText numberText;

    public ListMealsInterface listMealsInterface;
    public ListGeneratedInterface listGeneratedInterface;
    ArrayList<Meal> listMeals = new ArrayList<Meal>();
    ArrayList<Meal> generatedList = new ArrayList<Meal>();

    private static final String PREFS = "PREFS";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meals_fragment, container, false);
        numberText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.number_meals);

        listMealsInterface = (ListMealsInterface)getContext();
        listMeals = listMealsInterface.getList();

        //The error comes from here
        listGeneratedInterface = (ListGeneratedInterface)getContext();
        generatedList = listGeneratedInterface.getListGenerated();

        Button generateButton = view.findViewById(R.id.generate_list_button);
        generateButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(getNumberMeals() <= maxSavedMeals() ) {
                    closeKeyboard(view);
                    saveNumberInSP();
                    resetIsPresent();
                    loadFragment(new ListGeneratedFragment());
                }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.number_meals_over_limit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            }
        });

        loadFragment(new ListGeneratedFragment());
        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is the interface :

```
package com.example.application;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface ListGeneratedInterface {
    public ArrayList<Meal> getListGenerated();
}
```

It is overrided in another fragment where the variable I want to share is created, which only returns the variable.

I hope someone can help me, I have no clue to solve my problem...

Comment: is MainActivity implementing that interface?

Comment: no it is not, because the variable I want to share is created and defined in another fragment

Comment: Can you precise the type of your variables ? And give them a more precise name because  "where the variable I want to share is created, which only returns the variable."
is a litlle unclear. Does variable is always the same thing ?

Comment: My variable is ```ArrayList<Meal> generatedList```. It is created in a fragment A, but I need to use it in another fragment. In order to do this, I created the ListGeneratedInterface, which is defined (using @Override) in fragment A. But when I try to use it in the fragment above, I get the error I posted.

I think the problem comes from the use of ```getContext()```, because MainActivity doesn't implements ListGeneratedInterface (as generatedList is defined in fragment A). You can see I successfuly implemented ListMealsInterface in the code above, which is implemented in MainActivity